# EOFException on opening a buffered object stream

Tags: java, buffer, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm testing the `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` classes
tried to warp both in buffered stream object ..

```
File file = new File("file.lel"); //Assuming the file exist and has data stored in it.   
//will truncate file   
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));   
 ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) //Bad Practice!  
) {   
SomeObject writeMe = new SomeObject(1, 2, 3, 50.5, 'k'); //Object with 3 ints, a double and a char    
final double D = 30.3; //for testing   

out.writeDouble(D);  
out.writeObject(writeMe);   
out.flush();   

double DAgain = in.readDouble();   
SomeObject readMe = (SomeObject)in.readObject();   
readMe.printInfo();   
}   

//Some catch blocks...
```

But i'm getting EOFException on line 3 in the code above

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException //header loaded first .. ?!
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

When i removed the buffer stream objects, code worked .. i.e.

```
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
 ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))
) { ... }
```

Why this behavior? any idea?

Comment: That's not your real code, to start with - it would be `FileInputStream`, not `FileIntputStream.` It would be helpful if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Fundamentally, I don't think you *should* be trying to do what you're doing... you've already acknowledged that it's a bad practice, so why do it?

Comment: @JonSkeet this is all what i have in main method, and that was typo ! .. and i was just trying too see what happens if i do so ..

Comment: My point is that the typo means that clearly isn't the code you actually ran - which means there could be *other* differences as well. Always provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and make sure you've run the exact code you posted. Now, why would you *want* to do this? It looks like you've run into an implementation detail which wouldn't be relevant if you were doing something more sensible, i.e. only trying to initialize the input stream after you'd written data to the output stream.

Comment: You've got code labelled 'bad practice'. If you know it's bad practice why are you doing it? and if you don't know why it's bad practice why have you so labelled it?

Comment: @EJP there's a reason why i did that bad practice .. i'm testing the behavior of something here. sorry this is just how i learn .. by doing stupid things .. i wouldn't be doing this in a REAL CODE .. surly i wouldn't have posted this question if this _bad practice_ didn't work in the second example .. i just wanted to know why it was error in the first code and worked in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, *don't do this*. Don't try to initialize the input stream until you've got data in the file.

As for why it's working when you don't buffer, I believe the problem is with the buffering of the *output* stream... in the buffered version, you're creating the `FileOutputStream` which will truncate the file, then wrapping that in a `BufferedOutputStream`, then wrapping that in an `ObjectOutputStream`. The last of these will write the preamble data to the stream - but it only gets as far as the `BufferedOutputStream` which buffers the data. When you try to create an `ObjectInputStream` reading from the file, it's trying to *read* the preamble... but there's nothing to read.

You can demonstrate this easily:

```
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Not disposing of any resources just for simplicity.
        // You wouldn't actually use code like this!
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        // Flush the preamble to disk
        bos.flush();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    }
}
```

Without the `flush()` call, you get the the exception you've seen - *with* it, there's no exception.

As I say though, you simply shouldn't do this in the first place, IMO.

Comment: turns out that problem was declaring the ObjectOutputStream before the ObjectInputStream .. so the file is truncated .. i swapped the two lines and it worked correctly .. of course this requires the file to have data in it. if the file is newly created and empty the same exception will be thrown .. anyway it's the empty file, as you said about initializing an input stream with empty files .. you're right .. my questions are always dull. anyways .. thanks

Comment: i'm talking about the buffered objects of course .. this seems how buffers work as you explained. the other code without the buffers truncates the file as well but no exception is thrown.

Comment: @Mr.Cat: Were you expecting to read the data from the *old* file? That wasn't *at all* clear. If you're trying to read data from the old file while simultaneously overwriting it, I'd again suggest you don't do that. Just write to a different filename instead.